# Custom Cocoa Framework and a problem using it

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, import, void

I made a custom cocoa framework just to experiment and find the best way to make one but ran in to a problem using it. The framework project builds and compiles just fine, but when I use it in an xcode project I get the error, `'LogTest' undeclared`. The name of the framework is LogTest

Heres the code to my app that uses the framework:

TestAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <LogTest/LogTest.h>

@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {

NSWindow *window;

}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

TestAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
[LogTest logStart:@"testing 123":@"testing 1234"]; //This is the line where the error occurs
}


@end
```

Framework Code........

LogTest.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Method.h"


@protocol LogTest //Not sure if this is needed I just wanted a blank header


@end
```

Method.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface Method : NSObject {

}


+ (void)logStart:(NSString *)test:(NSString *)test2;

  @end
```

Method.m:

```
#import "Method.h"


@implementation Method

+ (void)logStart:(NSString *)test:(NSString *)test2 {
NSLog(test);
NSLog(test2);
}

@end
```

If anyone knows why I am getting this error please reply.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you include the contents of Logtest.h?

Comment: Are those typos in your post where you say AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m. The header file is named TestAppDelegate.h right?

Comment: Yes thanks for noticing I'll fix them.

Comment: happyCoding25: You don't need that protocol. There is nothing wrong with a framework having a main header that just imports other headers in the same framework. (I do question naming your class “Method”, though.)

Comment: The name "Method" was just for a test.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see of the header files you just posted. LogTest is not a class but an  empty protocol. You should be calling `logStart::` on `Method` not `LogTest`

IOW. change it to

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [Method logStart:@"testing 123":@"testing 1234"];
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get a whole new set of errors in the build results.

Comment: Those errors were likely being hidden by the previous error. The same matter before was that you were calling methods on a class that didn't exist.

If you post your new errors we can see if we can help.

Comment: Ok well thanks the new error seems to be common in xcode: 
dyld: Library not loaded: (a long path here)
  Reason: image not found

Comment: If I remember correctly that is something to due with the XCode not finding the dylib for the framework at runtime. A copy needs to be in the either /Library/Frameworks /System/Library/Frameworks or in the build folder of the product.

Comment: Or, you need to copy the framework into your app. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880-BAJJBIEF